# How does Google Chrome Instant Omnibox work?

Tags: google-chrome, google-instant

How does *omnibox instant* in Google Chrome 9 work ?
I enabled developer panel and checked, but didn't find any XHRs being fired... Is the Omnibar hidden from developer panel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part is done in C++, so you won't see it in the developer panel; you can use [Google Codesearch for Chromium](http://www.google.com/codesearch?vert=chromium) to view the Chromium source code. Of interest may be [InstantController](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/instant/instant_controller.h&q=InstantController&exact_package=chromium&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc) and [TemplateURLFetcher](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/search_engines/template_url_fetcher.h&q=TemplateURLFetcher&exact_package=chromium&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc). It's not the easiest code to follow, because it is written in the asynchronous style (the instant bits register an observer that gets invoked when the suggest URL has been fetched).

Comment: You can watch/inspect network activity, which should reveal various endpoints.

I can tell you that the page that appears during chrome instant has a generic url, like google.com/search?someConsistentCrap&ion=1 There's no q parameter, I could find the url if anyone wants.

Comment: That url is: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8 - - This then becomes https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=sf%20%20&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=c9b42f8de8a69eef&bpcl=37189454&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&biw=1186&bih=729 - with a # that also contains the search parameters.